# Ensure scheduled event only runs once a day?

Tags: java, scheduling

In a hobby project of mine, a "smart home" for controlling lights, I'm planning to create a feature which turns off all lights at a given time of day. There are also several other features which runs on command.

I've created a stack of events which are checked on an interval of (n) seconds. The program simply iterates trough each event in the stack, asks them to evaluate if they should be run, and then continues.

For the "on command" events I simply discard the event out of the stack after they're ran.

However for my planned feature I need the event to evaluate itself, run if the time of day is correct, and then go back into the stack - without firing again on the next iteration.

My problems is that I can't tell the event to run exactly at (for example) 12:00:00 as the interval for checking events isn't that exact (this may indicate other problems in my logic?). Neither can I use a flag to indicate that the event has ran, as it is supposed to run again the next day (in 24hrs).

To give some context: The idea behind the event stack is to provide a queue for incoming commands which are coming trough a REST Service (with multiple users).

*Update*: A possible solution may simply be to reschedule the task after it's completed. However I'm leaving the question open a bit longer in case someone has an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you're having problems getting it to run at an exact time, give it an interval to run, say from 12:00:00 -> 12:05:00 and once it runs inside that period, set a flag. Then, in another period, say, from 12:05:00 -> 12:10:00 check for that flag and clear it so that you can run it again in 24 hours. you can change these periods or move them to make them work for your timing needs (maybe make them hours instead of 5 minutes)

Comment: Good suggestion. I had been thinking along those lines myself, but hadn't been able to work out how the flag should be reset.

Comment: This also has the added benefit of knowing whether the process was run r not. If you don't find the flag inside that reset loop, you could have some sort of error reporting system

Comment: Sure, one of the many benefits: I generally like this concept (after playing with a few other ideas), so I'm marking this as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

If you set firstTime to currenttime rounded up to next minute, the timer will run at 12:00 if you set period to 60000

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to @Ray Trask I'm already using the Timer Class. Since the event stack should support events that need to run straight away I want to avoid creating Timer tasks which will be fired immediately (to avoid overhead).